# Python highlighting in emacs

Tags: python, emacs, highlight

I am using emacs 23 -nw and xterm installed on Debian Squeeze. I need highlighting with python but I don't have it. How can I enable it?

Edit:
Thanks for all answers, the problem is that

- I have googled a lot, really.
- I have the code on a file with extension .py
- The script starts with #!/usr/bin/python, as one of the the answers points I have changed to !#/usr/bin/env python
- I used M-x and tried to find something related to python, well there many options which do not solve my problem.

Sorry my question was not very precise and I even accept -10 but I don't have highlight which would give me red highlight for lines starting # etc. To be more precise I have a very a dull highlight; lines with # are white, lines between """ """ are green, **some** of the variable names are yellow but don't know why not all. [import, as, from] are light blue, [open, max, and other function names] are dark blue etc. And besides my 200 lines of code is working.

Comment: @event_jr: While heimatlos should have googled, that kind of response isn't appropriate for stackoverflow - here, we want clear questions, and clear answers, such that Googling becomes an old-fashioned activity.

Comment: @Arafangion Look at the related questions to the right.  The top one is about exactly this.  This is getting meta, but what should we do about terse questions, which are FAQ, asked without any detail as to what the specific problem could be?

Comment: @even_jr: So it is a failure to use stackoverflow, not google. :)

Comment: @Arafangion google as in the verb not the service.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run Emacs from `xterm` with `emacs -nw`, you'll have a different color layout than if you run the same color mode in an X window. Differences include big changes in the highlighting of comments, different colors assigned to various keywords and (rarely in my experience, though Python comments seem to fall into this category) failure to highlight some elements.

I'm not really sure why this happens, but it doesn't seem to be a problem on your end since it's consistent on every machine I've worked on. If it really bugs you, and you really, really want to keep running from `xterm`, take a look at the [color-theme](http://www.nongnu.org/color-theme/) module, it may help.

Comment: Thanks, I followed the instructions on the [color-theme](http://www.nongnu.org/color-theme/) page and now I have a descent highlighting. :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is right, but try the following.

1) M-x

2) type in "python-mode". Tab completion works here so type in "pyth" and hit tab and you can see what your options are.

mj

Comment: I've now tried exactly this.  Typing "pe" shows 3 possible completion options, amongst them "perl-mode".  Typing "py" shows no options.  I think python-mode must not be installed on my GNU Emacs 21.4.1.

Answer (score 1):

Emacs 23 should know about Python out of the box. Does the name of your Python file end with `.py`, or does the file have `#!/usr/bin/env python` as the first line? If you're creating a new file, make sure the filename ends with `.py`. You can also use `M-x python-mode` as mentioned in another answer. If none of that works, check that your terminal actually supports color.